# Drawing balls from a box

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have a box with $n+1$ white balls and $k(n+1)$ black balls. One white ball and $t$ black balls are signed with $1$ and the rest (so $(n+1)+k(n+1)-t-1$) with $0$. We draw one ball from this box and denote:

$A -$ drawn ball is white

$B - $ drawn ball has $0$ on it

$A, B$ are independent. How many black balls have $1$?

**My solution:**

$A \perp B \rightarrow \Bbb P(A \cap B)=\Bbb P(A)\cdot \Bbb P(B)$

$\Bbb P(A\cup B) =\Bbb P(A)+\Bbb P(B) -\Bbb P(A)\cdot \Bbb P(B)$

$\Bbb P(A)= \frac{n+1}{(n+1)+k(n+1)}=\frac{1}{k+1}$

$\Bbb P(B)= \frac{(n+1)+k(n+1)-(t+1)}{(n+1)+k(n+1)}=1-\frac{t+1}{(k+1)(n+1)}$

$\Bbb P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{k+1}\cdot (1-\frac{t+1}{(k+1)(n+1)})$

$\Bbb P(A\cup B)=1-\frac{t}{(n+1)(k+1)}$ as an union of these events comprises White$1$, White$0$, Black$0$.

$1-\frac{t}{(n+1)(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k+1} + 1-\frac{t+1}{(k+1)(n+1)}-\frac{1}{k+1}\cdot (1-\frac{t+1}{(k+1)(n+1)}) \rightarrow t=...$

Am I right?

Comment: The naive guess is $t=k$

Comment: @Henry and it's exactly what I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are independent then $A$ and $B^c$ are independent and $\mathbb P(A \cap B^c)= \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B^c)$

so $\frac{1}{(n+1)+k(n+1)} = \frac{n+1}{(n+1)+k(n+1)} \frac{t+1}{(n+1)+k(n+1)}$ i.e.  with cancellation $1=\frac{t+1}{1+k}$ and so $t=k$